# Enabling Query Service in Couchbase

Tags: java, service, sql++

Creating this topic as i have query on the couchbase.

I have setup. cocuhabase Node and i have missed to enable the query service while setting up the node.

Can somone help me to enable the query service as i need to run som N1QL queries from the console,

Hi Team

Creating this topic as i have query on the couchbase.

I have setup. cocuhabase Node and i have missed to enable the query service while setting up the node.

Can someone help me to enable the query service as i need to run som N1QL queries from the console,

Answer (score 0):

You can add separate node with query service.
You will not able to add service existing node (unless remove the node and re add)